# JavaScript: Dynamically created html-like string won't tun into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, innerhtml, createelement

in DOM I already have a wrapper

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

which I need to fill with bunch of divs, where each will represent new category. 
Each category will be then filled with various cards representing items of that category. Like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div data-category="puppy">
    Dynamically created category wrapper
    <div class="puppy1">...</div>
    <div class="puppy2">...</div>
  </div>
  <div data-category="cat">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I use following code to create and fill category, but I always end up either having empty category or having a string inside reprenting the html.

```
var categoryWrapper = document.createElement("div");
categoryWrapper.setAttribute("data-category", key);
categoryWrapper.innerHtml = htmlString;
```

Here is a fiddle demo of my issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/uuqj4ad5/

I'll be grateful for a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, `innerHml` should be [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)([Javascript object properties are case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)) otherwise it simply add an additional property and nothing gets happened.

```
categoryWrapper.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

```js
var htmlString = "<div class='card'><div class='cardImg'><img src='http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg' alt='Puppy'></div><div class='cardContent'><div class='cardInfo'><p>Puppy Yawning</p></div><div class='cardDesc'><p>Awww!</p></div></div></div>";

var outerWrapper = $("#wrapper");
var categoryWrapper = document.createElement("div");
categoryWrapper.innerHTML = htmlString;
outerWrapper.append(categoryWrapper);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>
    Under this title various categories should be dynamically created
  </h3>
  <div id="wrapper">outerWrapper waiting for dynamic data...</div>
</div>
```

---

**FYI :** If you want to remove the existing content then use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
innerHtml
```

should be

```
innerHTML
```

Javascript is **case sensitive**

If you are using `jQuery` why do you want to mix jQuery and Vanilla JS.

```
var outerWrapper = $("#wrapper");

// I created new categoryWrapper object
var categoryWrapper = $('<div/>', {
                          html: htmlString
                       });
debugger;
// WHen I have the category filled with inner data, I will append it into outerwrapper
outerWrapper.append(categoryWrapper);
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uuqj4ad5/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my fiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/1xg18a3f/1/

your js code should look like this

```
// This is dynamically filled html template. The data comes from some JSON.
var htmlString = "<div class='card'><div class='cardImg'><img src='http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg' alt='Puppy'></div><div class='cardContent'><div class='cardInfo'><p>Puppy Yawning</p></div><div class='cardDesc'><p>Awww!</p></div></div></div>";

// This outer wrapper will in the end contain few categories
var outerWrapper = $("#wrapper");

outerWrapper.append('<div>'+htmlString+'</div>')
```